# acending repetitious function without array 1 22 333 4444 55555

Tags: c++, algorithm

F is a function that number x has been repeated in an ascending order f(x).

> x :   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
>
> f(x): 1   2   2   3   3   3   4   4   4   4

my function gets 'x' and gives 'f(x)' and it has to do it without array but it goes wrong in high numbers.

```
int main()
{
int n;
cin>>n;
int i=1,a=1;
if(n==1)
cout<<'1';
else{
    while(true){
    a++;
    i=i+a;
    if(i>=n)
        break;
}
}
cout<<a;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: The description is very unclear. Your table suggests that f(10) = 4, but you also say that f(x) = x?

Comment: i meant f repeats x, x times, i edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int f(int x) {
    return (x * (x + 1)) / 2;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int left = 1, right = n;
    while(left < right) {
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        int val = f(mid);
        if(val >= n) {
            right = mid;
        }
        else {
            left = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    cout << left;

    return 0;
}
```

Use binary search. Right now I am in mobile. I will add the explanation later if needed. Let me know if you don't understand anything.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

```
f(x) = floor(0.5 + sqrt(1 + 8 * (x - 1)) / 2)
```

**Explanation**

Well, since this is a mathematical problem, just solve it with math ;)

One thing to notice is the correlation between the table and the [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number):

```
h(x) = sum(range(1, x)) = x*(x + 1)/2 //triangular number

x        1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10

f(x)     1   2   2   3   3   3   4   4   4   4

h(f(x))  1   3   3   6   6   6   10  10  10  10
```

So how does that help us? Well, we can write a new equation:

```
h(f(x)) = x | x = max({n | f(n) = f(x)})
```

And logically for the inverse the following should apply:

```
h^-1(x) = f(x)
```

No we've got two options:

Call it a day and just solve the rest via brute-force:

```
i = 1
sum = 0

while sum < x:
    sum += i
    i++

return i - 1
```

Or build our function `h^-1(x)`:

```
h(x) = y = (x+1)x/2
h^-1(y) = x with h(x) = y

x ^ 2 + x - 2y = 0
```

solve for x using the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula):

```
x = 0.5 +/- sqrt(1 + 8y) / 2
```

Now this formula still lacks a few things:

- we get two results, one of which is negative. We can just throw the negative result away, so `+/-` turns into `+`
- this formula is 0-based. To be honest, I'm still trying to figure out why. Solution: simply decrement `y` by 1 to get the proper result
- while this formula returns the correct result for the matching numbers, i.e. `y = 3 -> x = 3`, it returns floating-point numbers for other input, so we'll have to round down appropriately

Putting it together:

```
f(x) = floor(0.5 + sqrt(1 + 8 * (x - 1)) / 2)
```